# Allow scrolling in only one <div> on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, touchmove

Working on a web app, and I want to prevent the screen moving around, so I start with this:

```
 $(document).on("touchmove", false);
```

... then I realize I have a `div` that needs to be able to scroll, so I've added:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).parents().hasClass( 'touch-moveable' )) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Works ok, but now scrolling on mobile within that div can cause the whole screen to move around again. Not the end of the world, but... isn't there some way to make everything stay still and only let the one div move around?

**EDIT**

Ok this works, although I bet it could be consolidated and made way more elegant?:

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).parents().hasClass( 'touch-moveable' )) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

$('.touch-moveable').on('touchmove',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Try `$('.'touch-moveable'').on('touchmove',function(e){e.stopPropogation();)`

Comment: Ugh, I hate to be dense, but help me out a little. I'm super confused about delegation and stopPropagation when it comes to preventDefault ... am I stopping the propagation of touchmove, or stopping the propagation of of preventDefault??

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thanks @RayonDabre

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Propagation is misspelled; second to last line should be `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Thanks Mike, fixed it.